# Why isn't my program correctly accepting and using char inputs from text file?

Tags: java, file-io

I have created a java program to calculate interest earnings for accounts whose details are listed in a text file. The program is supposed to read the lines from the file (which each consist of an int, two doubles, and a char), calculate interest earnings, and print results. Three example lines from the text file would look like this:

31415  100.00  10.0  A

26535  200.00  15.5  D

89793  414.17  22.0  Q

I have written exceptions for unacceptable balances, interest rates, and compounding types.

When I run the program, the exception for compounding types gets thrown, even though the letters A, Q, and D (for annually, quarterly, and daily) are supposed to be accepted.

If I temporarily remove the exception and run the program, interest earnings for each line are calculated, but they are calculated incorrectly. Instead of taking into account the compounding types, everything is calculated once at an annual rate (instead of 4 times quarterly, or 365 daily, which I have methods set up to do).

My code for reading from the file looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class InterestCalculator

public static void main(String[]args) {

inputfileOpened = false;
do {
    try {
        inFile = new File(inputFileName);
        fin = new Scanner(inFile);
        inputFileOpened = true;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
          fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
} while (inputFileOpened = false);

while ( fin.hasNext() ) {
    acctNum = fin.nextInt();
    beginBal = fin.nextDouble();
    annualInterestRate = fin.nextDouble();
    compoundType = fin.next().charAt(0);

Investment customer = new Investment (beginBal, annualInterestRate, acctNum, compoundType);
}

fin.close();
```

The exception handling code in the Investment class looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Investment {

private double investorBeginningBalance; 
private double investorAnnualInterestRate; 
private int investorTerm; 
private char investorCompoundingType; 

public Investment2(double beginBal, double annualInterestRate, int 
        acctNum, char compoundingType) {

if (investorBeginningBalance < 1 && investorBeginningBalance 
            > 6000){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The beginning balance value "
                + "entered was invalid. The entry of " + beginningBalance +
                " will be ignored.");
    } else {
        investorBeginningBalance = beginningBalance;
    }

if (investorCompoundingType != 'A' && investorCompoundingType != 'a' 
            && investorCompoundingType != 'Q' && investorCompoundingType != 'q'
            && investorCompoundingType != 'M' && investorCompoundingType != 'm'
            && investorCompoundingType != 'D' && investorCompoundingType != 'd' {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The compounding type \n"
                + "entered was invalid. The entry of " + compoundingType + 
                " will be ignored.");
    } else {
        investorCompoundingType = compoundingType;
    }
```

So why isn't my program accepting my character inputs, through the exception handling and for further calculations in my later methods, where it is essential that the correct characters are passed into the correct equations?

I was thinking that the line:

compoundType = fin.Next().charAt(0);

might be causing the problem, but I don't see why it should, especially when the letters are definitely getting through.

When the exception is thrown, it reads "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The compounding type 
entered was invalid. The entry of A will be ignored."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `while (inputFileOpened = false);`?? No no no